# Import text files into mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, text, import

For a current assignment, I must import 2 .txt files into a MySQLdb with python. I'm having immense trouble. I have tried various methods and I simply can't do it.

I've searched through this site and many others over the past few days and I simply cannot get this to work. Whenever I've tried to adapt another person's solution to my own code, it fails - so I figure I should ask for help directly for my own code.

This is what I have so far:

```python
import MySQLdb 

# connect to database
mydb = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","0dy5seuS","cars_db")

# define the function
def data_entry(cars_for_sale):

# cursor creation
    cursor = mydb.cursor()

#load the file 'cars_for_sale.txt' into the database under the table 'cars_for_sale'

    sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'cars_for_sale.TXT'
        INTO TABLE cars_for_sale
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'"""

    #execute the sql function above
    cursor.execute(sql)

    #commit to the database
    mydb.commit()

    #call data_entry(cars_for_sale) function
    data_entry(cars_for_sale)

    mydb.close()
```

I can hardly wrap my head around it, any help would be appreciated it.
I now get the following feedback from the testing function:

> Trying:
>       data_entry("cars_for_sale") Expecting:
>       The number of rows inserted to cars_for_sale is 7049
>   ********************************************************************** File "**main**", line 4, in **main** Failed example:
>       data_entry("cars_for_sale") Exception raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\doctest.py", line 1289, in __run
>           compileflags, 1) in test.globs
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>           data_entry("cars_for_sale")
>
> File "E:/Uni/104/Portfolio 2/MediumTask_DataStatistics/question/TEST2_data_statistics.py", line 270, in data_entry 
>   data_entry(cars_for_sale) *it repeats this last portion several hundred/thousand times"
>
> The following few lines are after the repeated error above.
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line
>   243, in cursor return (cursorclass or self.cursorclass)(self)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 51, in
>   **init** from weakref import proxy RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I'm aware that this is an infinite recursion although I have no idea how to stop it.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately SO is not really a tutorial site. Please read the [FAQ} and [Ask] for tips on writing appropriate questions.

Comment: Where are you calling functions you have created? you have created 2 functions with same name but different argument types? What is that for?

Comment: In regards to 2 functions with the same name: data_entry("cars_for_sale") data_entry("car_details") It is because the testing function for this assessment tests those function names. I could not think of any other way around it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code reproduces your error `"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"`:

```
def data_entry(cars_for_sale):
    data_entry(cars_for_sale)
```

You don't need recursion here (and it is used incorrectly anyway).

> I'm aware that this is an infinite recursion although I have no idea how to stop it.

Just remove the `data_entry` call inside the `data_entry` function.